# ios swift CoreMedia CMFormatDescriptionRef linker error

Tags: ios, swift, linker-errors

I'm trying to read a format descriptor from one of my AVAssetTrack's with the following code:

```
var audioTrack:AVAssetTrack = self.asset!.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)[0] as AVAssetTrack
var formatDescription:CMFormatDescriptionRef = audioTrack.formatDescriptions[0] as CMFormatDescriptionRef
```

The problem is the downcast "as CMFormatDescriptionRef". I can declare a variable with type CMFormatDescriptionRef just fine but with the downcast I'm getting a linker error despite having added the CoreMedia framework and an "import CoreMedia" in my swift file. This is the linker error I get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CMFormatDescription", referenced from:
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to link your project with CoreMedia.framwork.

Comment: on what iOS or OSX you try to build this? what is your target?

Comment: I fixed this by reintalling xcode. I think there might have been a problem with my frameworks.